# Question about convergence in $\mathcal D(\Bbb R)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Let $\phi\in \mathcal D(\Bbb R)$. How to prove or disprove convergence of $\phi_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} \phi(nx)$ in $\mathcal D(\Bbb R)$?

I tried to do this by definition (we have to check two conditions of convergence):

(1) Because of $\operatorname{supp} \phi_n\subset\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{supp}\phi$, we have that $supp \phi_n$ is limited and closed (by the definition of $\operatorname{supp}\phi_n$) and therefore, $\operatorname{supp}\phi_n=K$, $K$ is a compact in $\Bbb R$.

Now, I am not sure how to check the following second condition.

(2) How to prove or disprove uniform convergence of $\phi^{(\alpha)}_n$ on compact $K$?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** look at the sequence of derivatives.

Comment: $\phi_n(x)$ converges to zero. For the first derivative, we have $\phi'_n(x)=\phi'(nx)$, but I can't see if this converges to zero or not?

Comment: And such a sequence cannot converge uniformly to $0$, except $\phi$ is itself $0$.